# How to get suggestion in typescript with "type JustifyContent = 'center' | 'flex-start' | string"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

Here is the code:

```
type JustifyContentProperty = 'center' | 'flex-start' | string

const justifyContent:JustifyContentProperty = 'cen..' // I expected 'center' suggests, but none.
```

[image]

Question:

1. How can I get property suggestion with this type? expected showing 'center' 'flex-start', but because of "| string" definition it shows nothing.
2. I met this problem because [csstype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype) library has a type -- CSS.JustifyContentProperty which can't trigger expected suggestions because of '| string', I wander if any other solution?

Comment: Why not just define `type JustifyContentProperty = 'center' | 'flex-start'`?

Comment: Because the type is comes from a library -- csstype

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This requires a trick:

```
type JustifyContentProperty = 'center' | 'flex-start' | string & {}
```

With this change, any `string` is still assignable to `JustifyContentProperty`, but you will get IntelliSense for `'center' | 'flex-start'`.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but the `type JustifyContentProperty = ..... ` is predefined in csstype library, I don't intend to modify it, so how can I make a change based on that type? I tried  `type JustifyContent = JustifyContentProperty & {}` and it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, there is nothing you can do (except for contributing the trick upstream). `JustifyContentProperty` mixes string literals with `string`, which effectively widens the whole thing to `string`. Once widened, there is no way to get IntelliSense back.

Comment: Again, thank you so much. I still wander why the author designed like this? I found out some of the types aren't mixed with string so I can get intelliSense, but some are, like JustifyContentProperty. Is that considered the possibility of extends more properties in the future?

Comment: That's my guess. The author probably wanted to support values not yet defined by the standard. In my opinion, it would be better to only use the well-known values and get rid of `string`. The CSS standard changes infrequently, and if one *really* does need a different value, they can always cast it.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions, IDE will give you type suggestions

```
// solution 1
type JustifyContentProperty = 'center' | 'flex-start' 

// solution2 use const enum
const enum position {
  'center',
  'flex-start'
}
const justifyContent = position.center
```